# Apache Nifi on QNX

Tags: java, jvm, sensors, qnx, apache-nifi

I have been reading about the possibilities of Apache Nifi. In this article http://www.zdnet.com/article/hortonworks-cto-on-apache-nifi-what-is-it-and-why-does-it-matter-to-iot/

and in Hortonworks website there are examples of using Nifi while simulating trucks events (speed, etc). http://hortonworks.com/hadoop-tutorial/realtime-event-processing-nifi-kafka-storm/#section_3

How come they suggest the scenario of vehicle sensor collection and filtering with Nifi when the main OS in cars is QNX and it does not support Java? Being JVM a main requirement for installing Apache Nifi. It is just some PR marketing?

In the article is mentioned "it's important to be able to prioritise the data that gets sent and maybe only send the summary level information and if an anomaly is detected. Then from the central processing area you can go back and request more data from that particular unit."

Making the point of minimizing data transfer on expensive connections (mobile data) by configuring the sensor collection from the central processing area seems impossible if QNX (and therefore the sensor data producer unit) does not support JVM.

Answer (score 2):

There is a subproject of Apache NiFi called [MiNiFi](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MINIFI/MiNiFi), which (among other things) aims to have agents on devices and such in order to collect data at its point of creation. This will include native agents, thus a JVM will not be required. The proposed roadmap is [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MINIFI/Proposed+Roadmap), it mentions the development of native agent(s)